# Is it true or false??

Tags: complex-analysis

There exists no function $f$ that is analytic in the unit disk $\Delta $ such that $$f(1/n)=f(-1/n)=n^{-2k+1}\quad \forall n\geq 2$$ 
where $k \in \mathbb{N} $ is fixed.

Comment: Remember that the zeroes of a nontrivial analytic function must be isolated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apply the **isolated zero principle** twice: if the zero set of an analytic function on the connected open set $\Delta$ has a limit point in $\Delta$, then $f$ is zero on $\Delta$.
>
> [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35767/if-f-g-are-both-analytic-and-fz-gz-for-uncountably-many-z-is-it-tru/35768#35768) for a proof by Andres Caicedo.

Assume such a function exists and consider the limit point $0=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ in the following two cases.

1. From the first equality, the function $f(z)-f(-z)=0$ on $\Delta$, i.e. $f$ is even.
2. From the second equality, we get that $f(z)-z^{2k-1}=0$ on $\Delta$, i.e. $f(z)=z^{2k-1}$ is odd.

So $f$ is both odd and even, i.e. $f(z)=0$ on $\Delta$. Contradiction with the second equality.