# Analytic function on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I am trying to prove the following but I am not sure how to use the compactness:

Let $f$ be a real analytic function on a compact set $K$. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence in $K$ such that $f(x_n) = 0$. Prove that $f = 0$.

I would appreciate a hint. Thank you!

Comment: What dimension has the ambient space? $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ for which $d$?

Comment: $R$ is in 1D. real numbers.

Comment: Hint, Since $K$ is compact, it is also sequentially compact.

Comment: But, you must require that the sequence $(x_n)$ has infinitely many distinct terms.

Comment: I hope $K$ is connected; otherwise the statement is false; consider $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & x\in[0,1] \\ x & x\in[2,3]\end{cases}$$ and $x_n=1/n$.

Comment: yes I know that and  am trying to use the expression of f as an infinite sum around the limit of a converging subsequence of x_n but I am not sure how to prove that that series goes to 0

Comment: if K is in R 1D and it is compact I assume it is an interval right?

Comment: @WhatsMyName: How is $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ not compact?

Comment: Indeed I was in a hurry but yes K is connected.

Comment: This has been asked here before. See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/35768/462), for example.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Thank you!